# Converting python hangman game to GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've written a hangman type game in python and I'm trying to convert it to a GUI program, unsuccessfully thus far. 
This is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def getHint(word, guesses):
    hint = ' '
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in guesses:
            hint += '_ '
        else:
            hint += letter

    return hint

def loadWordList(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    line = file.read().lower()
    wordlist = line.split()

    return wordlist

def countOccurences(word, guess):
    length = len(word)
    i = 0
    total = 0
    while i < length:
        if guess == word[i]:
            total += 1
        i += 1

    return total

def play():
    word = random.choice(loadWordList('words.txt'))
    guesses = []
    remaining = 10

    while remaining > 0:
        hint = getHint(word, guesses)
        remaining = str(remaining)
        guess = guess.lower()

        while guess.isalpha() == False or len(guess) != 1:
            output = 'Invalid input. Please enter a letter from a-z.'

        if guess in guesses:
            output = 'That letter has already been guessed!'

        else:
            if guess not in word:
                output = 'That letter does not occur in the secret word.'
            else:
                output = 'That is a good guess! ' + str(guess) + ' occurs ' + str(countOccurences(word, guess)) + ' time(s) in the secret word'
                guesses += guess
                remaining -= 1

        if '_' not in getHint(word, guesses):
            result = 'Congratulations! You guessed the secret word: ' + word
            break

    if remaining == 0:
        result = 'Sorry, the secret word was: ' + word

def buttonClicked():
    play()
    getHint(word, guesses)

root = Tk()
root.title('Guessing Game')

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding='3 3 12 12')
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

guess = StringVar()
output = StringVar()
hint = StringVar()
remaining = StringVar()
result = StringVar()

a_label = ttk.Label(frame, text='Enter a letter to guess: ')
a_label.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
a_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=7, textvariable=guess)
a_entry.grid(column=2, row=1,sticky=E)

b_label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=output)

c_label = ttk.Label(frame, text='Current Hint: ')
c_label.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E)
d_label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=hint)
d_label.grid(column=2, row=3)

e_label = ttk.Label(frame, text='Guesses Remaining: ')
e_label.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E)
f_label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=remaining)
f_label.grid(column=2, row=4)

button = ttk.Button(frame, text='Submit', command=buttonClicked)
button.grid(column=3, row=5)

g_label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=result)
g_label.grid(column=1, row=6)


for child in frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.bind('<Return>',)

root.mainloop()
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

- line 77, in buttonClicked - play()
- line 52, in play - guess = guess.lower() 
  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guess' referenced before assignment

Any tips as to how I can rearrange this code further to get the functions to actually connect with the GUI would be very much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can workaround that error by declaring guess as global in play() but there are more problems in here. Like converting StringVar guess to string guess or using while loops when you can use if etc.

Comment: There's really a lot going on that needs to be fixed.  Some things I found were:  `remaining` is converted into a string in play(), but you're still using it as if it were an int when you do `remaining -= 1` and `while remaining > 0:`.  Maybe you could use two variables, one to hold the int and one to hold the string.  When I put in an invalid input (ex. `1`) the game appears to go into an infinite loop.  This seems to be the problem: `while guess.isalpha() == False or len(guess) != 1:`.  There's no way to break from that!  Maybe change that to an `if` statement, and rework your flow control.

Comment: You can use Python's built in "count" to count occurrences --> print word.count(guess)  Also, you have to get the contents of an Entry http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: If the person guesses the word correctly on the tenth try you will print "Sorry", etc because remaining will be zero.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it is just as it says it is, the variable "guess" is not defined.
You probably wanted to do something like

```
guess = word.lower()
```

and not

```
guess = guess.lower()
```

Small tip: Use PEP8, it will help others read your code.

Comment: I changed it to word.lower() although guess.lower worked in my initial program, but now the program just crashes without any errors printed.

Comment: I don't know if word was really the thing you wanted there, it just seemed the most logical to me. I suspect that you get a different error now. Try print statements in various places of your code, that way you at least know where it crashes. Also, what do you use to execute your code? Executing it from command line might work better if you don't already do that.